# Slicing Strings for python

Tags: string, character, slice

> Write a function `slice_from(string, start, end)` which returns the characters in `string` from index `start` up to, but not including, index `end`.

I have this in my code:

```
part = s[1:]
print(part)
```

Comment: What's your question? Did you google for "Python string slicing"? (e.g. http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have python installed on my work computer so I wasn't able to test it, but this should work:

```
def slice_from(string, start, end):
    returnVal = "";
    for x in range (start, end -1):
        returnVal += string [x];
    return returnVal;
```

Also it may be beneficial to read up on more [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) or learning Python online for free at someplace like [CodeAcademy](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)